# How to store dictionary into database like key and value pairs have seperate fields in diango

Tags: python, mysql, django

In python  file I have dictionary `dict1` the key of `dict1` is `item` and value is `frequency`.

I want to store this database in django. I have already created model named `display` for this!
Can you please help me solve this and how to store dictionary in database using  MySQL?

Comment: hi there, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. you will easily find at least a starting point googling your question. if you get stuck it it the right time to ask at stackoverflow.

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json fields for that two store the dict data in db, for the postgres database

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model
from django.db import models

class Dog(Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  data = JSONField()

dog = Dog.objects.create(name="test", data={'1':'1'})
```

for more info

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

for mysql please check

https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html

Comment: Sir in the above code where we are using dictionary

Comment: @NeeharikaBanisetti please see now

Comment: Sir actually I want to store a key and value as seperate fields in database

Comment: hey you can create the modle with key, value fields key will be unique